# Combining use of Laravel old helper with or

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, helper, isset, or-operator

Say what I want to achieve is this:

```
@if(isset($responseValue))
    {{ old("name", $responseValue) }}
@else
    {{ old("name"), "" }}
@endif
```

Basically saying that if $responseValue is set, then I want form input to have value default to it - as if reading from existing value during form edit - and update to new "name" value when user enters new value and submits and fails and it gets flashed back. Otherwise if $responseValue is not set, then there's no need to read $responseValue into form input.

My question is can I get a more efficient equivalent:

```
{{ old("name", $responseValue or "") }}
```

or perhaps?

```
{{ old("name", $responseValue) or "" }}
```

I've tried both and they don't work. I wonder why syntactically for the first example, $responseValue or "" won't be evaluated first before old("name", $responseValue or ""). I tried putting into brackets too ($responseValue or "").

Answer (score 0):

I used `{{ old("name", $responseValue) or "" }}` and saw that's ok.
If you need a sure way. Let's try the code below

```
$oldValue = !isset($responseValue) ? old('name', '') : $responseValue;
```

Comment: I just tried {{ old("test_name", $foo) or "Empty value" }}, where $foo is null. And it didn't work. I get the error "ErrorException in 4eac12e0142e3bff4009bc7b11fc0e1e695743c6.php line 137:
Undefined variable: foo". I'm using Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0):

The old helper uses the second param as a fallback.

```
old("name", $responseValue)
```

If "name" is not set, it will output the $responsevalue